# dbt referencing the wrong python install

Tags: python, conda, dbt

I'm using dbt to build some data transformations. I've had this work reliably in the past, but after a pip / conda installation conflict I decided to just do a fresh conda install. I have not ceased to regret this decision :(

At any rate, I've got dbt running in a conda env set up to mimic our production environment. However, now when I attempt to test a dbt transformation in my local environment thus:`dbt run --models {model_name} --target dev`

I get the following error:

`zsh: /usr/local/bin/dbt: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: no such file or directory`

When I run `which python`, I get

`/Users/{me}/opt/anaconda3/envs/{env_name}/bin/python`

This looks to me like dbt is assuming the wrong python directory location, but I'm not sure how to set it right.

Comment: What's the output of `which dbt`?

Comment: @NilsWerner - looks like it's ```/usr/local/bin/dbt``` - so am I not running the version of dbt that's in the environment? I'm not sure how to interpret that

Comment: Yes, exactly. Did you really install it inside the env?

Comment: Well, this result certainly suggests that I did not. One more try.

Comment: If you are developing using VS Code, there is a nice extension that lets you see the current python interpreter, and VS Code will easily detect virtualenv in your source folder to automatically use the python in that virtualenv when starting your vs code terminal. In the official dbt doc, they make you install the environment in a "dbt-env" folder and following their guide should make everything work out of the box on VS Code. If running on a separate terminal, you'll just have to `source [dbt-dir]/dbt-env/bin/activate`

Comment: your dbt path `/usr/local/bin/dbt` suggests you probably installed it with brew. you should be able to uninstall it using brew, _you might hit an issue since the python3.7 seems to be removed_. after you remove your existing dbt, create a virtual environment and install dbt inside of it, and then activate the virtual environment when you need to work on your dbt project. there are better tools (such as poetry) to manage your project dependencies more strictly, which you may want to look into. note that would increase your project complexity a fair bit.